# Control WIX Features Install/Uninstall Order

Tags: wix, windows-installer, wix3.8

Is it possible to control the order of `install/unintall` of `Wix Features`? I am not sure if they are installed/uninstalled in the order they are defined in `Product.wxs` file. Could not find any documentation either.
Mostly I am concerned about uninstall order, I need to control the order in which features are uninstalled.

Comment: What type of element is it that requires a specific sequence? A CustomAction? Or something else?

Comment: Well - I have a number of websites and related apppools. Some of the sites make requests to others, so at the time of undeployment, I need to control the order of uninstall.

Answer (score 2):

You can't control the order in which features are installed or uninstalled because that's not the way Windows Installer works. If you were to look at the MSI file with Orca and look at the order (by number) in the InstallExecuteSequence table you'd see actions like RemoveRegistryValues, RemoveFiles, RemoveFolders. These actions remove (for example) all the files in the product, not just the files (or registry entries) for a particular feature.

The short answer is that you can't control the order in which features are removed. It appears that you have asked a [classic XY question](http://www.perlmonks.org/?node=XY%20Problem) and it might help to ask about the underlying problem you are trying to solve that leads you to believe that controlling feature uninstall order might help solve.